# AWS Lambda Javascript for AudioPlayer

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to code in Javascript on AWS Lambda.  The code is meant for Alexa to go to a URL and stream the audio on there using the AudioPlayer.
Can't figure out what I am missing in this code or what is wrong with it and I get this error through the log.

Code:

```js
'use strict';

var alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

var APP_ID = "amzn1.ask.skill.b5c95058-7134-4044-9e77-a4279e0adaf7";

var PAUSE_MESSAGE = "paused!";
var RESUME_MESSAGE = "resumed!";

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {
  'play': function(audioURL, offsetInMilliseconds) {
    var response = {
      version: "1.0",
      response: {
        shouldEndSession: true,
        directives: [{
          type: "AudioPlayer.Play",
          playBehavior: "REPLACE_ALL",
          audioItem: {
            stream: {
              url: 'https://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/275202399-amazon-web-services-306355661-amazon-web-services.mp3',
              offsetInMilliseconds: 10
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
    this.context.succeed(response);
  },
  'AMAZON.PauseIntent': function() {
    this.emit(':tell', PAUSE_MESSAGE);
  },
  'AMAZON.ResumeIntent': function() {
    this.emit(':tell', RESUME_MESSAGE);
  }
};
```

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'alexa-sdk'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:13)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my code.

Code:

```js
var lastPlayedByUser = {};
var streamURL = "http://cpdc101-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ISNCPDCMB1_1@314337/master.m3u8";


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var player = new Player(event, context);
    player.handle();
};

var Player = function (event, context) {
    this.event = event;
    this.context = context;
};

Player.prototype.handle = function () {
    var requestType = this.event.request.type;
    var userId = this.event.context ? this.event.context.System.user.userId : this.event.session.user.userId;

   if (requestType === "LaunchRequest") {
        this.play(streamURL, 0);

    } else  if (requestType === "IntentRequest") {
        var intent = this.event.request.intent;
        if (intent.name === "Play") {
            this.play(streamURL, 0);

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.PauseIntent") {
            this.stop();

        } else if (intent.name === "AMAZON.ResumeIntent") {
            var lastPlayed = this.loadLastPlayed(userId);
            var offsetInMilliseconds = 0;
            if (lastPlayed !== null) {
                offsetInMilliseconds = lastPlayed.request.offsetInMilliseconds;
            }

            this.play(streamURL, offsetInMilliseconds);
        }
    } else if (requestType === "AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped") {
        this.saveLastPlayed(userId, this.event);
        this.context.succeed(true);
    }
};


 Player.prototype.play = function (audioURL, offsetInMilliseconds) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Play",
                    playBehavior: "REPLACE_ALL", 
                    audioItem: {
                        stream: {
                            url: audioURL,
                            token: "0", 
                            expectedPreviousToken: null, 
                            offsetInMilliseconds: offsetInMilliseconds
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};


Player.prototype.stop = function () {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            shouldEndSession: true,
            directives: [
                {
                    type: "AudioPlayer.Stop"
                }
            ]
        }
    };

    this.context.succeed(response);
};

Player.prototype.saveLastPlayed = function (userId, lastPlayed) {
    lastPlayedByUser[userId] = lastPlayed;
};

Player.prototype.loadLastPlayed = function (userId) {
    var lastPlayed = null;
    if (userId in lastPlayedByUser) {
        lastPlayed = lastPlayedByUser[userId];
    }
    return lastPlayed;
};
```